# Can I use a login manager to choose different window managers?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, window-manager, i3, login-manager

I'm working towards an Arch install with a tiling window manager (probably i3) but was wondering whether it's possible to use a login manager and have the Gnome 3 desktop available as a fallback.

So that one user would have the option to select either the Gnome desktop, or the i3 window manager on login. Or would it only be possible for different users? Or wouldn't it be possible at all?

Comment: I think almost all DM (display manager) can do it. Check here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most display managers let the user choose a session type when logging in. The primitive xdm doesn't but more recent ones such as gdm, kdm, lightdm, etc. do. There's a directory, usually either under `/etc/X11` or under the display manager's configuration directory, that records session names with the program associated with each name. [Under Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager#Session_list), the location is `/use/share/xsessions`. So just ensure that your favorite window manager or session manager is listed.

Comment: And there's no need for differentiation for WM specific files in the home folder? Say that I have an .Xresources file in my home folder for i3, wouldn't that conflict with the Gnome desktop?

Comment: .Xresources isn't specific to a window manager. It contains application settings only, which are used by the application they're for. If you want different application settings on different DEs that's a different story, you can run `xrdb -merge` on another file.